# Webpack DevServer -> proxy HTTPS resource -> UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: node.js, webpack, https, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Webpack DevServer with the following settings:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '*': {
            target: 'https://localhost:44369',
            secure: true
        }
    },
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hot: true,
    https: false
}
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https

It has worked fine with `HTTP` but when I'm now switching my proxy to `HTTPS` I start getting errors.

Got the following message in command prompt:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request / from
>   localhost:8080 to https://localhost:44369
>   (UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE)
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

I have tried to set Node `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to `0` but this does not help.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED': 0
})
```

Is there some way that I can access the generated certificates CA and add this to Trusted Root Certification Authorities? Will this help or do I need to change other things as well?

If I switch `https` to `true` I get the same error.

> Generating SSL Certificate
>
> ...
>
> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request / from
>   localhost:8080 to https://localhost:44369
>   (UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE)
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

When I access the desired resource in Chrome I also get the following error:

[image]

**Update:**

I have now set webpack-dev-server to use the same certificate as my original web server (https://localhost:44369) does. I have verified that the `Thumbprint` and `Serial number` are identical between the two.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-pfx

```
https: true,
pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Client.WebProxy/App_Data/Certificate/") + '\\localhost.pfx'),
pfxPassphrase: 'securePassword'
```

[image]

I also tried with injecting the certificate with `ssl-root-cas` but I still get the same error.

```
var sslRootCAs = require('ssl-root-cas/latest')
sslRootCAs.inject();
```

Tried this as well:

```
target: 'https://[::1]:44369',
```

https://github.com/saikat/react-apollo-starter-kit/issues/20#issuecomment-316651403

```
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
rootCas.addFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Client.WebProxy/App_Data/Certificate/") + '\\localhost.pem');
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas

```
https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Client.WebProxy/App_Data/Certificate/") + '\\localhost.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Client.WebProxy/App_Data/Certificate/") + '\\localhost.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Client.WebProxy/App_Data/Certificate/") + '\\localhost.pem'),
}
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Spent way to much time for this when in the end it was so easy. It worked by setting `secure` to `false` for proxy and then accessing webpack-dev-server via http.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '*': {
            target: 'https://localhost:44369',
            secure: false
        }
    },
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hot: true,
}
```

Comment: Great solution! This configuration is the quickest path to victory for most dev environments, imho.

Comment: I get a 403 forbidden after the 101 socket upgrade. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

In my case using `secure: false` was not enough to make the error go away. If you are using a [Name-based virtual host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) you might need to set `changeOrigin` to true for not keeping the origin of the host header.

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/path': {
            target: 'https://backend-server',
            secure: true,
            changeOrigin: true // <-
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy